# Detecting Edges in a Region on Screen

Tags: automation, edge-detection

Without getting into too much detail, I need to detect and trace an edge where there is a significant contrast change - but only in a small region of the screen. Is there a library that selects a region of interest, then traces it somehow? I'm doing some very repetitive work with CT scans of bone.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  What language are you using? Other toolkits?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified!  I'm using Python; I've used some libraries (e.g. PyAutoGUI) for light automation, but nothing like this.